# Font size is not same, when html is converted to Word using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Tags: c#, html, ms-word

I trying to convert html file to MS word (docx) file.
Using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word I am able to convert from HTML to Word but font size is not same for both html and word format of file. 
Whatever formatting (font size) I had done in html is lost in Word file. Can anyone help me to retain the same font size.

Here is the code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document wordDoc = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();

wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref filepath, ref confirmconversion, ref readOnly, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,                                              ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

object fileFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocumentDefault;

wordDoc.SaveAs(ref saveto, ref fileFormat, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oallowsubstitution, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using that code to convert

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document wordDoc = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();
            Object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            wordDoc = word.Documents.Add(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
            word.Visible = false;
            Object filepath = "c:\\page.html";
            Object confirmconversion = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            Object readOnly = false;
            Object saveto = "c:\\doc.pdf";
            Object oallowsubstitution = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            wordDoc = word.Documents.Open(ref filepath, ref confirmconversion, ref readOnly, ref oMissing,
                                          ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                                          ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                                          ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
            object fileFormat = WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF;
            wordDoc.SaveAs(ref saveto, ref fileFormat, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                           ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                           ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oallowsubstitution, ref oMissing,
                           ref oMissing);
```